# What does "that ship never left the port" mean?

Tags: phrases, idiom-meaning

I've heard this used in Britain (specifically England).
Could someone explain to me what its meaning is?

Comment: What do you think it means? Without any context, who can say?

Comment: I haven't heard it with context - it is only someone else who told me the phrase and I said I didn't know what it means. I was thinking it may be a common phrase?

Comment: Could mean "2 cans short of a six-pack"...or "ain't gonna happen", or "the boat did not clear customs"...without context we have no idea.

Comment: That ship will never sail is often used to describe a scheme with obvious flaws which are bad enough to prevent success. Never left the port sounds like anther way of saying "never got off the ground" *i.e.* never even got started.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an variation on the more common phrase

> "That ship's already sailed"

This generally refers to a missed opportunity. For example, if you were planning on applying for a job, and then heard that someone had already got it, you might say,

> "Well, looks like that ship has already sailed".

Here the ship is a metaphor for the job, but more generally it is a metaphor for any kind of opportunity.

I would expect that the phrase

> "That ship never left the port"

would have a fairly similar meaning. But perhaps instead of the opportunity going to someone else or you being too late to take advantage of it, it would refer to a situation where a seemingly promising opportunity is never taken advantage of or, as suggested by @WayfaringStranger, was held back by its own flaws.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. A ship that never left port is used to address a variety of things.
A person who has never moved out of their comfort zone, doesnot venture forth, has not weathered life, hasnot left home, has not experienced life beyond their immediate existence, hasn't 'sailed" - can refer to sex, relationships, etc.
A ship that has never left port usually never will. Could be aperson that will grow old with Mimmy and never marry, etc